# Can i allow a user to modify a work item while denying him from create a new one

Tags: tfs

I am setting up a tfs 2013 environnement,
In a Scrum team project, we would like a few users to be able to create backlog items and tasks, but we would like that other users to only be able to change the task their are assigned. Or at least we would like that these users can modify existing tasks, while not being able to create new one, or move them to other sprints

at this time, with the security parameters i have found, i can only either allow a user to do everything (create and move a backlog items from a sprint to another, modify it, delete it...), or nothing (if you can't create or move, you also can't modify an existing one...)

any clue how i could proceed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have custom work item types and we prevent users from creating certain work items by editing the WIT's xml and including this in the transition between nothing and the "New" state. [global]\TeamSystem-TaskCreation is a TFS security group with a limited set of members.

```
<TRANSITION from="" to="New" for="[global]\TeamSystem-TaskCreation">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to do this I'm afraid. TFS does not have many fined grained access controls, the impression I get is that it is designed to empower people and not restrict them.

You should be able to ask people not to change tasks, if that is your way, and use the Work Item History and/or Alerting functionality to know when they have done something you don't want them to. For example, and task changes not by approved people sends and e-mail to the leads.